# ResultSetMetaData method getTableName return empty string

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm trying to get the tables involved in a SQL query from a PostgreSQL database. However, the getTableName method always returns an empty string.
Here is part of my code:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db?" +
 "user=root&password=root&useSSL=false");
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
 ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs;
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
if (!rs.next()) {
 System.out.println("No records found");

} else {
 do {
  RowsNumber++;
 } while (rs.next());
}




rs.beforeFirst();
for (int j = 0; j <= RowsNumber; j++) {
 while (rs.next()) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
   System.out.println(rsmd.getTableName(i));

  }

 }

}
conn.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
 System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
 System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Edit your Question to specify the version of Java, the version of Postgres, what JDBC driver make and version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of the driver are you using? That might be a issue with the PostreSQL JDBC driver implementation. Just took a look at implementation for 9.1.jdbc4 version and found that it just returns an empty String.

[image]

There is another way to get that by using `metadata.getColumns(null, "%", tableName, "%");`

Take a look on this example [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/934007)

Comment: It seems to be implemented in the 42.2.5 driver (just looking at the source).

Comment: I'm using this version of jdbc driver 9.0-801.jdbc4. Thank you